# I am displaying the contents of an Excel file in a Gridview. How do I handle merged cells?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I want to read and display an excel file in a web page. I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` in .aspx.cs and GridView in .aspx. I am  just reading it into a DataTable and binding it to GridView.

The problem with this is, I can't handle merged cells. For example, if two columns are merged in Excel, while displaying, it will show two columns with the value in first cell and second cell will be empty. I just want to retrieve the sheet as it is. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` is designed to provide programmatic access to excel files. It will do some formatting work (see `Text` property) but most of the difficulty of rendering is left to the consumer (your program).

`MergeCells` will return `True` if you have a merged cell and `MergeArea` will return a `Range` containing the merged cells. You can then use the `RowSpan` and `ColumnSpan` fields of the `GridView`'s cells to duplicate the functionality.